# How to choose 3 positions from array, deleting each one after it was chosen?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have to randomly choose three positions from an array and then set text on three textViews to those positions. How can I do it so there's no risk of choosing the same two items? I looked into a couple of ways, but none of them seem to be applicable, or I'm just too inexperienced to utilize them. Would greatly appreciate any help!

Here's what I've got so far.

```
 qs2 = qs.clone();

    //Calling the TextViews and Image Views from motivatorscreen.xml


    Question1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question1);
    Question2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question2);
    Question3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question3);



  int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(qs2.length);
    int randomIndex2 = new Random().nextInt(qs2.length-1);
    int randomIndex3 = new Random().nextInt(qs2.length-2);



    String randomQuestion = qs2[randomIndex];
    String randomQuestion2 = qs2[randomIndex2];
    String randomQuestion3 = qs2[randomIndex3];




    Question1.setText(randomQuestion);
    Question2.setText(randomQuestion2);
    Question3.setText(randomQuestion3);

}
```

But then with the code, as it is now there's a risk of choosing the same thing twice, and I'd like to get rid of it. Any hints on how to achieve it?

Comment: You could assign the index of the chosen item to a variable, and compare it to the other 2 variables also containing the indexes of the other two items, once you've randomly chosen the 3 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare global variable Use do-while the like this

```
int randomIndex=0,randomIndex2 =0,randomIndex3 =0;   //declare global 


randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(qs2.length);

do{
  randomIndex2 = new Random().nextInt(qs2.length);
 }while(randomIndex ==randomIndex2 );

do{
 randomIndex3 = new Random().nextInt(qs2.length);
 }while(randomIndex2 ==randomIndex3 );
```

Comment: Hmm, I did that, but now it always chooses the same position three times...

Comment: see edited answer.while should be check equal .now its working fine

Comment: Make sure that qs2.length is always higher than 3 .Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

An usual approach is to shuffle your existing array and then take first 3 items:

```
// Assume n is number of questions
List<Integer> indexes = IntStream.range(0, n).boxed().collect(toList());
Collections.shuffle(list)
// Get number in index 0, 1, 2
String randomQuestion = qs2[indexes.get(0)];
String randomQuestion2 = qs2[indexes.get(1)];
String randomQuestion3 = qs2[indexes.get(2)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Set` of `Integers`, create a while loop, and just use `set.add(someNumber)`, until the set has a size of 3.

A `Set` **will not** contain duplicates, so it will have you covered.

for example:

```
Set<Integer> myRandomSet = new HashSet<>();
while(myRandomSet.size < 3){
   int random = new Random().nextInt(qs2.length);
   myRandomSet.add(random);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array with the numbers that you want to choose randomly from, and then when ever you choose a number from the array you can delete it, this way there no possibility of the same number to be chosen more than once